# vscode shortcut for folders view collapse

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find the command in vscode to bind a shortcut.

by default, there are three sections in sidebar: folders, outline and timeline
most useful for me are two first ones, and I'd like to handle those by shortcuts.

to collapse/expand outline section, there are a commands:

```
outline.focus - expand the view 
outline.toggleVisibility - collapse the view
```

For folders section, I found only commands :

```
workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer - to expand view
workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders - ???
```

but second one is not what I'm looking for - it collapses the folders inside the view, but do not collapse the view itself.

any idea how to collapse/expand Folders view?